# how to free a localhost port on mac

Tags: google-chrome, localhost, angular5, macos-high-sierra

I have read the posts similar to this but to no avail.

I am in the midst of a comprehensive tutorial for Angular (5). I am on MacOs High Sierra 10.13.3. I am using Chrome Version 64.0.3282.140 (Official Build) (64-bit).

I just completed one project in the tutorial. I am now trying to complete the next project in the tutorial. The project is set to use the default port 4200 on localhost. All of the projects have executed this way.

I have performed my npm install. My npm start script is simple, = "ng serve". I enter npm start and it serves up the project as expected. I then go to my browser and enter the address localhost:4200. The previous project renders. I can't get the current project to render. These are the things I have tried to remedy the situation:

1. sudo lsof -i tcp:4200
2. changing the start script to ng serve --port 4300 and then using the address localhost:4300 (tried it with 5000 too)
3. Actually the first thing I did was look for an active activity on port 4200 in the Activity Monitor
4. Clear my Chrome browsing history
5. Restart my computer.
6. Tried the same process using Firefox as a browser
7. Tried it using Brave as a browser

In each and every case when I enter localhost:(anything) I get the previous project. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If I could delete this question I would. I discovered the problem.

I only THOUGHT I was pointing to the new project. In reality, I was pointing at the old project. THAT is why the same thing kept coming up and that is why nothing I tried would work.

I am embarrassed. Clearly, I am still a rookie. I hope no one spent any time on this.